# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: []

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbctemplate

Hi I am new to hibernate and named query.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: []

Without passing the sectorId the query is working as expected. But after passing sectorId getting the above error. sectorId is received as List. Ex- sectorId= [250, 254];

```
[SELECT CM.COMPANY_NAME_FULL as companyNameFull ,
        MAX(CM.COMPANY_ID) as companyId , 
        CM.TICKER as Ticker, CM.YEAR_ENDING as YearEndingId, 
        CM.gics_id 
FROM DETAILS_SMT  SM 
    JOIN META_DATA CM ON CM.TICKER = SM.TICKER JOIN M_DETAILS M ON M.ID = SM.ID 
    JOIN SMT_MAPPING TCM ON TCM.TICKER = M.TICKER 
WHERE CM.TICKER NOT IN(:Ticker) 
AND SM.IS_DELETED='N' 
AND M.IS_DELETED='N' 
AND CM.NOMY=(   SELECT DISTINCT NOMY FROM META_DATA  
                WHERE TICKER=:Ticker 
                and cm.sectorId_id IN (:sectorId) 
            )
GROUP BY CM.COMPANY_NAME_FULL,CM.TICKER,CM.YEAR_ENDING
]
```

Java code:

```
Query nativeQuery= entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryConstants.GET_LIST_BY_SECTOR);
nativeQuery.unwrap(SQLQuery.class)
        .addScalar("companyId",new LongType())
        .addScalar("Ticker",StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        .addScalar("companyNameFull", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        .addScalar("YearEndingId", new LongType())
        .setParameter("sectorId", sectorId)
        .setParameter("Ticker", Ticker)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CompanyMetaMasterDto.class));
List<CompanyMetaMasterDto> list= nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you try renaming one of the `Ticker` maybe thats the issue.

Comment: If you can read it, just maybe you can debug it

Comment: sorry, my bad.. removed the duplicate setparamter. But the result is coming as empty